# get method returns root url content

Tags: c#, ajax, postman, webrequest, http-get

i try to ge the content of this url: https://www.eganba.com/index.php?p=Products&ctg_id=2000&sort_type=rel-desc&view=0&page=1

but as a result of the following code the response contains the content of this url, the home page: https://www.eganba.com

in addition, when i try to get the first url content via Postman application the response is correct.

do you have any idea?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.eganba.com/index.php?p=Products&ctg_id=2000&sort_type=rel-desc&view=0&page=1");            
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set the Content-Type Header? Seems like you are expecting a xml, so it should be application/xml or text/xml...

Comment: actually i'm expecting an html on the response. this header is for ajax call or sth. i have been trying many things but always returning the root url. any help providing me to take the content (it can be totally different from my code) will be appreciated.

Comment: ok. Strange thing is: actually i do get the content of the paging if i click the link... 5 minutes ago it brought me to the top-level page...

Comment: hmm that is strange. i always get the content of the paging on the browser when i clicked it. but if you have faced such a situation, i don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebClient method which inside System.Net. I think this code gives you what you need. It return the page's html

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    client.Headers.Add("accept", "text/html");
    var htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.eganba.com/?p=Products&ctg_id=2000&sort_type=rel-desc&view=0&page=1");

    var result = htmlCode.Contains("Stokta var") ? true : false;
}
```

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: this one is also returning the root page's content. did you run the code? does it return the actual url's content to you?

Comment: yeah it worked, thank you. i have also tried to modify headers but i couldn't get the result before. and i commented the 3 lines that contains "query". i don't know why you have added them?

Comment: @tpa yes, I tired some code for accessing absolute path html then i forget that about query codes. i removed them.

Comment: hmm now i realized that the url is slightly different than the first version i gave. anyway, thanks again.

Comment: and if it is possible for you to explain here, i would like to know how you did you manage to get that absolute path.